# What is an idiomatic way of saying "have always been, and will always be" in French?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

In English, this expression is sort of idiomatic, emphasising the meaning of "forever". How do you say the following sentence, for example, in French?

> I have always been, and will always be there for you.

I say this sentence in French as follows, but isn't this translation too literal? Is there some other more idiomatic phrase?

> J'ai toujours été là pour toi, et sache que je serai toujours là.

Comment: What have you found so far? We expect posters to make a minimum research effort before they ask for a translation. It's no more idiomatic in French than in English. Just [normal conjugation of *être*](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-%C3%AAtre.html). A dictionary will tell you [how to say  *always* in French](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/always) and a grammar page [where to place it](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-position-french-adverbs-in-sentences.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP hasn't made any research effort whatsoever before they asked the question.

Comment: Actually, I'm not asking for a simple translation. It's not at all difficult to translate this sentence literally. What I'd like to know is, as shown in my title, if there is any **idiomatic** phrase for this expression in French, because this is sort of a fixed expression (an idiom) in English that can take no other form.

Comment: For instance, the English expression "**Sleep on it**" can be translated into the French idiom/proverb "**La nuit porte conseil**", but both can never be translated **literally**. So I wonder if the same goes for the expression in my question.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and reformulate it. I'll gladly retract my close vote if you show you have searched how to say "I have always been / I always will be" (which is plain & usual English) in French and that you are looking for a different way of saying it, or that you are not sure about such or such a word/phrase  because...

Comment: What you propose is the usual way to say it. You can omit *sache que* but it's quite correct with it. It's as straightforward in French as it is in English.

Comment: From where I see it, this expression is not idiomatic in French, so a quite literal translation is fine. Yours is actually ok, while @Random's offers an elegant way not to repeat "là".

Comment: George Sand’s one-time use of it certainly doesn’t make it an idiom (or even idiomatic or grammatical, FTM), but she replaced both “LAs” with “Y” in [“J’y suis et {j’}y serai toujours pour vous.”](https://books.google.com/books?id=heIVAAAAMAAJ&q=%22j%27y+suis+et+j%27y+serai+toujours+pour%22&dq=%22j%27y+suis+et+j%27y+serai+toujours+pour%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifhJTl9tnMAhWKKB4KHUmSAiEQ6AEIMDAD) Granted she just covered the present & future (not the past), but it might work with “j’y étais/y ai été et j'y” You might even be able to omit the 2nd “{j’}” like the second “I” in English is omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to say it would be

> J'ai toujours été là pour toi, et je le serai toujours

Here, "le" stands for "là pour toi", since it is kind of heavy to repeat it twice. So here, you have a way to avoid it, so it will be smoother/nicer to use this shortcut, but you're not wrong if you don't.

Comment: This is the first time I have seen "le" used with "être" like this. I could understand the sentence just fine if it were "et je le ferai toujours" instead, but when "le" is used with "serai", what meaning/function does "le" have?

Comment: @régénérée Answer enhanced ! :)